# ¿Por qué tengo el error "Error sintactico cerca de else"?

Tags: bash, condiciones, unix, shell-script

Tengo este código:

```
puerto=false

    while ! $puerto ; do
     read -p " Intoduce puerto: (000 para salir)" port
     if [ $port -eq 000 ] then
      $puerto = true
     else
      echo ...
     fi
    done
    echo hola bro
```

Aparentemente está bien, pero me da el error:

```
Error sintactico cerca de else
```

Comment: en lugar de `$puerto = true` prueba a quitar los espacio igual que lo tienes en la primera linea. A bash se le puede ir un poco la olla con los espacios entre "="

Comment: @JoseRodriguez no es que se le vaya la olla, sino que no se ponen. `var="contenido"` es la forma de definirlo. `var = contenido` lo que hace es ejecutar el comando `var` pasándole `=` y `contenido` como parámetros.

Comment: Hace un tiempo resolví una pregunta similar aqui en SO y recordé de primeras la solución pero no los detalles. Por vagueria y prisas he puesto "se le va la olla"

Comment: @JoseRodriguez y [te dije lo mismo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/285777/revisions) :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mi con esta forma de expresión me funciona correctamente:

```
if [ $port -eq 000 ]
then
   ...
else
   echo ...
fi
```

Simplemente fue bajar el `then` una línea.

Comment: Cierto, bajando el 'then' funciona

Comment: `$puerto = true` no tiene ningún sentido en Bash. Esto lo que haría es ejecutar el comando contenido en la variable "$puerto" con el parámetro "=" y el parámetro "true".

Comment: Sugiero modificar la respuesta. Actualmente este código es erróneo.

Answer (score 3):

El `if` no funcionaba porque tenías `if [ condición ] then` directamente, pero debías poner un separador entre `]` y `then`: ya sea un punto y coma o un salto de línea.

Es decir, debes sustituir:

```
if [ condicion ] then
```

por

```
if [ condicion ]; then
#               ^
    ...
fi
```

```
if [ condicion ]
then
    ...
fi
```

---

Recomiendo pegar el código en https://www.shellcheck.net para ver los errores más grandes. Notas:

- usa dobles comillas siempre.
- usa una secuencia del tipo `while :` para hacer un bucle infinito y utiliza `break` para salir de ella cuando se cumpla cierta condición.

```
while :; do
   read -p " Intoduce puerto: (000 para salir)" port
   if [ "$port" -eq 000 ]; then
       break
    echo "..."
done
echo "hola bro"
```